# /dev/kvm is not found on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, kvm-virtualization

After I installed Android studio `2.2.3` on `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` this problem bugs me for hours:

[image: Error message]

I've checked the bios and it shows that vt-x is supported but I receive

```
me@pc:~$ kvm-ok 
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: For more detailed results, you should run this as root
HINT:   sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
```

in my terminal. I have also installed kvm follwing [this](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/10/09/install-kvm-kernel-based-virtual-machine-ubuntu-14-04-lts-desktop/) tutorial and I can see:

```
me@pc:~$ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
8


me@pc:~$ virsh -c qemu:///system list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
```

But emulator still refused to load.

```
me@pc:~$ uname -a
Linux pc 3.13.0-98-generic #145-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 8 20:13:07 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I get this error on the studio's console:

> Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD

I'm really ran out of ideas. I appreciate your help.

UPDATE:

```
root@pc:/home/me# sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: KVM (vmx) is disabled by your BIOS
HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
      and then hard poweroff/poweron your system
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get when you try the command `kvm-ok` gives you two other commands which may resolve your problem :

1. `sudo modprobe kvm-intel`(with intel CPU, replace, with `-amd` for AMD ones) or `sudo modprobe kvm` : this will load the kvm virtualisation module into the kernel, allowing VM to run properly.
2. running `sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok` : will run it as root.

The first one is the most likely to work, so try it first, and then run the second one.

EDIT :

I just noticed in your answer that you said your BIOS **supported** it, but not that it was **enabled**... It's probably just a misunderstanding from me, but check anyway...

Comment: I get this at 1: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_intel': Operation not supported`

Comment: Yes, please refer to update for the output.

Comment: Oh, my fault : it's `kvm-intel` and not `kvm_intel` :/ (By the way, there's a documentation page about it [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/kvm)

Comment: Interestingly ,  `sudo modprobe kvm-intel` also results in `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_intel': Operation not supported
`

Comment: @Karlom yes, probably. Try re-runing `kvm-ok`

Comment: That's right. The BIOS says it is `supported` but has no way to change it to `enabled` so I assumed that it was enabled.

Comment: `kvm-ok` still gives `/dev/kvm does not exist`

Comment: Maybe your BIOS (or UEFI ?) has an advanced mode, or requires to setup a password before changing certain options (happened to me once) ?

Comment: Good tip. let me try. I did not set the password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50467/discussion-between-cocosushi-ts-and-karlom).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: couldn't run AVD (Nougat x86_64 image).
How I solved: just enabled *Intel Virtualization Technology* in BIOS (at *BIOS Features* section for my Gigabyte motherboard).

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812624/android-studio-emulator-dev-kvm-is-not-found).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the tips already mentioned, newer AMD processors have a NX Mode setting that can be enabled/disabled in the BIOS. In my particular case, enabling NX Mode was also required.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1343245)

Answer (score -1):

1. sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
2. sudo adduser `id -un` libvirtd
3. sudo adduser `id -un` kvm

Then log out and back in again, and check that it is working by running:

virsh -c qemu:///system list

Comment: read the description carefully. I did all these from the tutorial that I've mentioned.

Comment: -un is a invalid option..